# heroku play! with sendgrid configuration

Tags: heroku, playframework, sendgrid

Tried to config smtp in `application.conf`

```
mail.smtp.host=smtp.sendgrid.net
mail.smtp.user=${SENDGRID_USERNAME}
mail.smtp.pass=${SENDGRID_PASSWORD}
```

And in the controller

```
MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
//... setting from,to,subject,content...
Mail.send(email); //using Play's util
```

But exception occurs, saying bad user credential when authenticating the smtp server.

One thing I notice is that, when push to heroku and start the app, it would warn:

```
   WARNING: Cannot replace SENDGRID_USERNAME in configuration (mail.smtp.user=${SENDGRID_USERNAME})
   WARNING: Cannot replace ENV_SENDGRID_PASSWORD in configuration (mail.smtp.pass=${SENDGRID_PASSWORD})
```

This may due to the precompile flag is on when deploy?? Here is my `Procfile`:

```
web:    play run --http.port=$PORT --%prod
```

Comment: Is that error at `git push` time?  If so, you can ignore it.  Are you getting an exception from `Mail.send()`?

Comment: no error at `git push`, just warning. The exception is from `Mail.send()` saying bad user credential. I tried if I use `System.getenv("SENDGRID_USERNAME")` directly in code and use `MultipartEmail`'s `send`, it can send. But in that case I cannot test locally with the built-in mail mock.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a simple Play + SendGrid + Heroku example that works for me:
https://github.com/jamesward/playsendgrid

I'm not sure what is different between this example and your code.  The only weird thing I noticed above is where it says `ENV_SENDGRID_PASSWORD`.  Perhaps that environment variable name is wrong.

Comment: Is there a way to use Play! configuration to send EMails using API Keys instead of passwords?